# Saving Excel sheets to CSV is slow

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

Trying to save all (5 page) sheets to separate csv file named as sheets.
This code is very slowly, it takes about 5 minutes to extract 5pages with only 30 rows and 4 columns on each.

```
<?php 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$xls  = 'test.xls';
echo convertXlsCsv($xls);

function convertXlsCsv($xls)
:bool
{
    $result = FALSE; // DEFAULT
    try {
        $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
        $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($xls);
        $sheetCount = $spreadsheet->getSheetCount();
        $loadedSheetNames = $spreadsheet->getSheetNames();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $sheetCount; $i++) {
            $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv($spreadsheet);
            $writer->setDelimiter(';');
            $writer->setEnclosure('');
            $writer->setLineEnding("\r\n");
            $writer->setSheetIndex($i);
            $writer->setUseBOM(true); //Writing UTF-8 CSV files
            $writer->save($loadedSheetNames[$i].'.csv');
            $result = TRUE;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo "Error";
    }
    return $result;  
}#endfunc
```

If I use `Xlsx` code is not working saying `Calculation error`

So how to quickly save all pages to csv?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the test file?

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/gb9u8x  test file

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: if I not accept it mean than no

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm it's slow for me as well, about 30 seconds for each sheet. The problem appears to be the use of `VLOOKUP`. If you reduce the search range to only search the filled in cells instead of the entire column, you'll get much faster performance.

```
=VLOOKUP(A18, codes!A1:B250, 2, FALSE)
```

Or, if you ensure that the **codes** sheet is sorted alphabetically you can use the [`LOOKUP` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb):

```
=LOOKUP(A18, codes!A1:A250, codes!B1:B250)
```

And it will also perform much more quickly.

Note that for some reason you can't fill down with either of these formulae. They require manual entry of the ranges. :(